# Covariant derivative fullfils Levi-Civita in Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$In our lecture, when we introduced the Levi-Civita connection, we had as an example the directional derivative of a vector field $X$ in direction of another vectorfield $Y$ in $\Reals^n$ defined by
$$
D_XY(p) := \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y(p + tX(p))-Y(p)}{t}.
$$
We have written down that this definition fullfils the Levi-Civita connection definition, but actually I don't even see why it is a connection. For example why does $D_{f \cdot X}Y = f \cdot D_XY$ for an arbitrary $f \in C^{\infty}(\Reals^n)$ hold?

My ideas: Interpreting p as a tangent vector one could use the $\Reals$-linearity of the vectorfield:
\begin{align*}
D_{f \cdot X}Y(p)
  &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y(p + t(f \cdot X)(p))-Y(p)}{t} \\
  &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y(p + tf(p) \cdot X(p))-Y(p)}{t} \\
  &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y(p) + tf(p)Y(X(p))-Y(p)}{t} \\
  &= f(p) \cdot \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{tY(X(p))}{t} \\
  &= f(p) \cdot \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y(p + tX(p)) - Y(p)}{t} \\
  &= f(p) D_X Y.
\end{align*}
Is that correct? Thank you a lot!

Comment: I recently answered http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843861/covariant-derivative-in-mathbbrn/1844001#1844001 which is on a similar point, well, you could derive this result from the formula there if you already had the formula in terms of components of the vector fields. It's immediate from the formula derived that the f(p) pulls out since $(fX)(p)_i = f(p)X_i(p)$ (although the $p$ is implicit in the linked answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point is that $f(p)$ is just a number, and the derivative depends only on $f(p)$, not on values of $f$ at other points. If $f(p) = 0$, there's nothing to prove. Otherwise, $t f(p) \to 0$ when $t \to 0$, and
\begin{align*}
D_{f\cdot X} Y(p)
  &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y\bigl(p + t(f \cdot X)(p)\bigr) - Y(p)}{t} \\
  &= \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y\bigl(p + tf(p)X(p)\bigr) - Y(p)}{t} \\
  &= f(p)\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y\bigl(p + tf(p)X(p)\bigr) - Y(p)}{tf(p)} \\
  &= f(p) \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{Y\bigl(p + tX(p)\bigr) - Y(p)}{t} \\
  &= f(p) D_{X} Y.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks a lot for enlighten me!!! Now I got the idea and will do the other axioms by myself for practice. Have a nice day!